# How to fix no module error in flask RQ worker

Tags: python-3.x, flask, redis, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to build a web application with Redis and a worker. Furthermore, I have the rq-dashboard to monitor.

The entire project is in vagrant- ubuntu environment

Project structure:

```
project/
       app_main/
                moduleA/
                        classA  - The task to do
                jobs.py    - Implements the job
                queue.py   - Has the code perform.queue(id)
      scripts/
              worker/
                     dockerfile
                     worker.py
      dockerfile
      docker-compose.yml
      app.py
```

The docker builds correctly, the app works fine. But when the worker runs it gives an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_main'

I added --path in the docker-compose rather than having a separate dockerfile, still got the error.

```py
# jobs.py
from flask_rq2 import RQ
from app_main.moduleA.classA import methodA

rq = RQ(redis_url="redis://redis:6379/0")

@rq.job
def perform(id):

    methodA().subMethodA(id)

    return True


# worker.py

import os

import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://redis:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    image: web
    environment:
      - MODE=dev
      - REDIS_URL='redis://redis:6379/0'
      - RQ_REDIS_URL='redis://redis:6379/0'
    networks:
      - app-net

  redis:
    image: redis:4.0.11-alpine
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
    hostname: redis
    networks:
      - app-net
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data


  dashboard:
    build: ./app_main/dashboard
    image: dashboard
    container_name: dashboard
    ports:
      - '9181:9181'
      - '6379:6379'
    command: rq-dashboard -H redis
    networks:
      - app-net
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data

  job_worker:
    build: ./scripts/worker
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - app-net
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data

# Docker network
networks:
  app-net:

volumes:
  redis-data:
```

Error Log

```
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m Traceback (most recent call last):
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 812, in perform_job
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m     rv = job.perform()
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 588, in perform
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m     self._result = self._execute()
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 594, in _execute
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m     return self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 199, in func
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m     return import_attribute(self.func_name)
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rq/utils.py", line 155, in import_attribute
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m     module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[31mjob_worker_1    |[0m ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_main'
```

Worker dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

ADD ./worker.py .

RUN pip install rq redis

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]

CMD ["./worker.py"]
```

Comment: What is the main script, the which you run to start the app? Is it `app.py`?

Comment: Yes its app.py. It is in the web container.

Comment: can you post your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: And your python path? (with `sys.path`)

Comment: @Mihai I edited it, with the docker-composer

Comment: Have you tried to give the job_worker access to the app as well with the same volume declaration as in the web service (volumes:  - .:/app)?

Comment: @Mihai I tried that too, still gives me the error. Ill add the error to the question.

Comment: Can you post the worker Dockerfile as well?

Comment: @Mihai added the dockerfile

Comment: I'm no python developer but from what I see the error comes from jobs.py when trying to execute "from app_main.moduleA.classA". Now I see jobs.py is actually inside the folder "app_main". Is that right? Maybe it should be "from moduleA.classA" instead? Again... I'm no python developer :)

Answer (score -1):

I tried many solutions, did not work.

The solution I did was, I placed the worker dockerfile to the root folder. Modified the dockerfile with WORKDIR ./app and installed the dependencies from pip install -r requirements.txt.